# How to plot a function curve in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lattice, r-faq

What are the alternatives for drawing a simple curve for a function like

```
eq = function(x){x*x}
```

in R?

It sounds such an obvious question, but I could only find these related questions on stackoverflow, but they are all more specific

- [Plot line function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162400/plot-line-function-in-r)
- [Plotting functions on top of datapoints in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853703/plotting-functions-on-top-of-datapoints-in-r)
- [How can I plot a function in R with complex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109257/how-can-i-plot-a-function-in-r-with-complex-numbers)
- [How to plot a simple piecewise linear function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737357/how-to-plot-a-simple-piecewise-linear-function)
- [Draw more than one function curves in the same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049674/draw-more-than-one-function-curves-in-the-same-plot)

I hope I didn't write a duplicate question.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626264/one-function-per-facet/70636329#70636329

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
> eq = function(x){x*x}
> plot(eq(1:1000), type='l')
```

[image: Plot of eq over range 1:1000]

(Or whatever range of values is relevant to your function)

Answer (score 117):

I did some searching on the web, and this are some ways that I found:

The easiest way is using curve without predefined function

```
curve(x^2, from=1, to=50, , xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

[image]

You can also use curve when you have a predfined function

```
eq = function(x){x*x}
curve(eq, from=1, to=50, xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

[image]

If you want to use ggplot,

```
library("ggplot2")
eq = function(x){x*x}
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1, 50)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq)
```

[image]

Comment: FYI the qplot example no longer works: To encourage users to use `ggplot()`, the `qplot()` function was crippled - so, for example, it no longer accepts the `fun` argument (as of v3?)

Answer (score 37):

`plot` has a `plot.function` method

```
plot(eq, 1, 1000)
```

Or

```
curve(eq, 1, 1000)
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not see your example `plot(eq, 1, 1000)` anywhere else. I also saw the `curve(eq, 1, 100)` example. Is there a difference?

Comment: @sjdh Not much. `plot.function` actually calls `curve` after doing some argument checking. Also, `curve` can take an expression as input, but `plot` needs a function as input to dispatch to `plot.function`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lattice version:

```
library(lattice)
eq<-function(x) {x*x}
X<-1:1000
xyplot(eq(X)~X,type="l")
```

[image: Lattice output]

Answer (score 2):

Lattice solution with additional settings which I needed:

```
library(lattice)
distribution<-function(x) {2^(-x*2)}
X<-seq(0,10,0.00001)
xyplot(distribution(X)~X,type="l", col = rgb(red = 255, green = 90, blue = 0, maxColorValue = 255), cex.lab = 3.5, cex.axis = 3.5, lwd=2 )
```

1. If you need your range of values for x plotted in increments different from 1, e.g. 0.00001 you can use:

> X<-seq(0,10,0.00001)

2. You can change the colour of your line by defining a rgb value:

> col = rgb(red = 255, green = 90, blue = 0, maxColorValue = 255)

3. You can change the width of the plotted line by setting:

> lwd = 2

4. You can change the size of the labels by scaling them:

> cex.lab = 3.5, cex.axis = 3.5

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 2):

As sjdh also mentioned, ggplot2 comes to the rescue. A more intuitive way without making a dummy data set is to use xlim:

```
library(ggplot2)
eq <- function(x){sin(x)}
base <- ggplot() + xlim(0, 30)
base + geom_function(fun=eq)
```

Additionally, for a smoother graph we can set the number of points over which the graph is interpolated using n:

```
base + geom_function(fun=eq, n=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Function containing parameters

I had a function (`emax()`) involving 3 parameters (a, b & h) whose line I wanted to plot:

```
emax = function(x, a, b, h){
  (a * x^h)/(b + x^h)
}
curve(emax, from = 1, to = 40, n=40 a = 1, b = 2, h = 3)
```

which errored with `Error in emax(x) : argument "a" is missing, with no default error`.

This is fixed by putting the named arguments *within* the function using this syntax:

```
curve(emax(x, a = 1, b = 2, h = 3), from = 1, to = 40, n = 40)
```

which is contrary to the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/graphics/curve.html) which writes *curve(expr, from, to, n, ...)* rather than *curve(expr(x,...), from, to, n)*.

Comment: It's not contrary to the documentation. expr is just the name of this argument and not a function by itself. It is defined as _The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x._ this means if you have more than just the name of the function it will evaluate the entire argument as an expression.

Comment: Hi @tjebo I agree that the expr argument is correct, but how they've written the "..." in the syntax suggests curve(expr=fun,...) works too which is not true. curve(expr=fun(x,...)) seems to be the only way.

Comment: no. the ... are for the "function method of plot" (this is just the R way to allow more flexibility in programming) - see `?curve`. Here, the documentation even specifies `For the "function" method of plot, ... can include any of the other arguments of curve, except expr.` - this makes it fairly clear that it does not relate to the expression. I think this documentation is pretty clear in this case.

Comment: P.S. I assume your confusion arises from other functions where you can add additional arguments to a function using `...` (e.g., lapply). However, this is just the way those are designed, and `...` takes different roles in each case, depending on the underlying function design. Also, methods are generally a special case of functions and sometimes can even contain `...` that have no meaning at all. I would therefore generally avoid blindly using `...` if you don't exactly know what it does for that function.