# Plotting a function curve in R with 2 or more variables

Tags: r, function, plot, contour, curve

How can I draw a curve for a function like `vpd = function(k,D){exp(-k*D)}` in R?

I want a plot of  `D` vs `vpd`(0:1)  assuming `k` is constant.

The only question I could find was [How to plot a function curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091323/how-to-plot-a-function-curve-in-r) . I've tried both of:

```
plot.function(vpd, from=0, to=1, n=101)

curve(vpd, from=0, to=1, n=101, add=FALSE, type = "l")
```

but only get

```
Error in -k * D : 'D' is missing
```

UPDATE: solved it!

```
vpd <- function(D,k=0.05){exp(-k*D)} # D is the x axis 
plot(vpd, from=1, to=100, ylim=0:1)
```

Comment: If you really want *"a plot of D vs vpd(0:1) assuming k is constant (=0.05)"*, then **that's not a 2D function plot, it's one single contour line of constant k(=0.05) on a 2D plot** (please fix your title). Also, do you want a function that automatically generates a sensible range of (k,D) to show the interesting parts of the plot, or do you want to manually supply the range of k?

Comment: Also if you want to plot D vs vpd=0:1, then really you're exploring the reverse-function D = -log(vpd) / k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Mamoun Benghezal's answer works for functions you define yourself, there may be cases where you want to plot a predefined function that expects more than 1 parameter. In this case, currying is a solution:

```
library(functional)

k <- 0.05

vpd <- function(k,D){exp(-k*D)}
vpd_given_k <- Curry(vpd, k = 0.05)

curve(vpd_given_k, ylim = c(0, 1),
      from = 1, to = 100, 
      xlab = "D", ylab = paste("vpd | k = ", k))
```

Comment: That nearly does it. The y-axis is right but I want the x-axis to be the length of D i.e. if D is between 0 and 20 that should be the scale on the axis rather than 0 to 1.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understand your comment because `D` is just a value and not a range. But I edited the answer such that the maximum of the x-axis is always `D`.

Comment: From the question, I think OP is hoping to plot against D and hold k constant. Of course, since D and k are interchangeable in this equation that's really just a matter of labeling.

Comment: The question is a little bit mysterious - what does plot "D vs vpd(0:1)" mean? Only "plot vdp vs D" makes sense for me; and this is what you also suggest. However, I don't understand the OP's comment if this is true. @user3725599 can you clarify how the final plot should look like?

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry for being vague. 

`vpd <- function(D,k=0.05){exp(-k*D)} # D is the x axis

plot(vpd, from=1, to=100, ylim=0:1) `

Comment: The I suppose the (latest) update of the answer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference? I've managed to use the "my" same method for functions with multiple functions.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `Curry` allows you to "permanently" set an argument to a value. This won't be necessary if the argument has a (correct) default value, but you need it when there's no default or when you want to speficy another value than the default one.