# How to graph a function with multiple parameters

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to graph this function `function(x1,x2,x3,x4){2 * x2 * x4 + x3 ( x1 - 2 * x4)}` using `curve()` in R. However, I'm being met with:

> Error in f1(x) : argument "x2" is missing, with no default

*`x1` `x2` `x3` and `x4` are all supposed to have different minimum and maximum values as well, but I'll worry about that after I can just get any graph to show up*

Comment: Why do you want to use `curve`? Since it was written to only accept one number in a range of [from, to] as stated in `?curve`

Comment: This is about R language, not about RStudio (which is just one IDE). Untagged [tag:rstudio].

Comment: Do you want a function which auto-generates a sensible default range of (x1,x2,x3,x4) to show the interesting parts of the plot, or are you ok to manually supply that parameter range yourself, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Curve** 
As I already mentioned in my comment I don't understand why you want to use `curve` since it is build to accept a **single** range of numbers e.g. 1,2,3,4 and then applies a formula to it. This makes plotting straightforward since the input numbers form the x-axis (thus 1,2,3,4...) and the formula results are plotted on the y-axis. In your case you don't have a single input range (actually you have four ranges: `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4`) and you cannot plot in 5D thus you have to pick one of `x1:x4` to display on the x-axis. Also you have `2 * x2 * x4 + x3 ( x1 - 2 * x4)` as formula however `.. x3 ( ..` cannot be directly interpreted by R therefore I added * to make `2 * x2 * x4 + x3 * ( x1 - 2 * x4)` **however if you meant that X3 should be multiplied with the numbers within brackets you should edit the formula in the code below**.

**Alternative**
As you mentioned "x1 x2 x3 and x4 are all supposed to have different minimum and maximum values as well" I would suggest to simply write your own plotting function, like so (I now displayed `x1` on the x-axis):

```
range.plot <- function( func, x1.range, x2.range, x3.range, x4.range ) {
  # Apply formula
  res <- data.frame(x = x1.range, y = func(x1.range, x2.range, x3.range, x4.range))

  # Plot using ggplot2
  ggplot(res, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
}


fun <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4){2 * x2 * x4 + x3 * ( x1 - 2 * x4)} # note the added *
range.plot(fun, seq(1,10), seq(10,29), seq(5,14), seq(1,10))
```

Which will produce this plot: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Plotting a function curve in R with 2 or more variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338854/plotting-a-function-curve-in-r-with-2-or-more-variables)

The link above looks similar to your question and might help you figure it out. You might have to add the function curry (in the functional package) to pre-specify parameters. Hope that helps.

Comment: That question is not strictly about a 2D function plot, but a single contour line of constant k(=0.05) on a 2D plot. Also, that is not about auto-generating a sensible default range of (x1,x2,x3,x4) to show the interesting parts of the plot, the OP manually supplies the parameter range. So, not really a duplicate, and not a great canonical either.