# Plot size = 1/{N∗⌈log2N⌉∗[(1/70)/60]} in R?

Tags: r, plot, logarithm

size = 1/{N∗⌈log_2(N)⌉∗[(1/70)/60]}

How can I plot this function with R?

(⌈⌉= ceil)

For example:
[image]

With label "size" for y-axis and "N" for x-axis.

N >= 2, N is natural Number (2,3,4,5,6,...)

Comment: `curve(1 / (x * ceiling(log2(x)) * ((1/70)/60)))`? Possible duplicate of [How to plot a function curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091323/how-to-plot-a-function-curve-in-r)

Comment: Not really... because this one is not a simple function :/ I draw an example of this - see above... it should looks like this...

Comment: @GenXGer Yes, really! ;-) You just need to show the function for the same range. Take a look at my example below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the function

```
f <- function(N) 1 / (N * ceiling(log2(N)) * 1/70/60)
```

Plot with base R in the range `[1,20]`

```
curve(f, from = 1, to = 20, n = 10^3, type = "p", cex = 0.1)
```

[image]

Plot with `ggplot2` in the range `[1,20]`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(N = c(1, 20)), aes(N)) + stat_function(fun = f, geom = "point")
```

[image]