# Using math notation in gt table cells

Tags: r, rstudio

Can math (latex) be entered into cells in a table generated by gt()?
The following produces output that writes latex code rather than translating into desired math symbols.

```
xxx <- tibble(x="$V_{11}$")
gt(xxx)
```

Actual result:

x
$V_{11}$

The desired result is typeset math.

Comment: This is usual only for Rmarkdown, but only for visual demonstration of equation. In script R do not need to follow Latex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091323/how-to-plot-a-function-curve-in-r

Comment: https://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/courses/s341/S17/from-class/MathinRmd.html