# problem with drawing graph of sum function in r

Tags: r

Let's take sample 'y' of length 100 from N(0,1) distribution and function g(x)=x^2+7.

I want to make a graph of function $h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{100}g(x-y[i])$

So

```
 y=rnorm(100,0,1)

 g=function(x){x^2+7}

h=function(x){sum(g(x-y))}
```

And now expressions like

```
curve(h)

plot(h)

lines(h)
```

doesnt work, can You please help me how can i draw graph of function h?

Comment: `h` is a function. You need to generate actual values to plot. Pick a range of values `x`, compute `hx=h(x)`, then `plot(x,hx)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a function curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091323/how-to-plot-a-function-curve-in-r)

Comment: Disregarding other issues, given the way you've defined your function `h`, it cannot possibly be used to plot anything, since it returns a single scalar value (namely, the `sum` of whatever is passed to `g`).

Comment: This works: `curve(Vectorize(h)(x))`