# When I modify a duplicated (copied) Geom object, this also modifies the underlying original Geom. Why?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

When I modify parts of a duplicated Geom object, this also modifies the underlying original Geom. Why?

<sub>(Big big thanks to user Stefan to identify this problem via comment on a now deleted previous question of mine).</sub>

```r
library(ggplot2)
GeomFunction$required_aes
#> [1] "x" "y"
GeomFunction2 <- GeomFunction
GeomFunction2$required_aes <- c("x", "y", "fun")
GeomFunction$required_aes
#> [1] "x"   "y"   "fun"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Because `is.environment(GeomFunction)` and environments do not follow copy-on-modify heuristics that most R objects such as vectors adhere to. The correct way to copy a ggproto object for modification is to use `GeomFunction2 <- ggproto(NULL, GeomFunction)`. Or `ggproto("GeomFunction2", GeomFunction)`.

Comment: Not an answer to your "Why?", but see also [Extending ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html): "To create a new geom or stat, you will just create a new `ggproto` that inherits from `Stat`, `Geom` and override the methods described below." But also: "As you read this document, you’ll see many things that will make you scratch your head and wonder why on earth is it designed this way?"...

Comment: @Henrik yes, I forgot about that fabulous sentence in this document. To be fair, I just wasn't aware of the environment nature of a ggproto object, and this was truly enlightening.

Comment: @tjebo In entirely agree, I just posted the link for future reference. I think the environment part (your _why?_) could be more explicitly described in the docs. I also recall some issues on the ggplot github where people have been bitten by this modification "by reference" property. Thus, your question (and its answer) was indeed great! Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because ggproto class objects are environments instead of list-like structures, as can be checked with `is.environment(GeomFunction)`. Environments do not follow the copy-on-modify heuristics that e.g. a vector adheres to.

The correct way to make a copy for modification purposes is with the `ggproto` constructor. Technically, you're making a child instance of `GeomFunction`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

GeomFunction2 <- ggproto(NULL, GeomFunction)
GeomFunction2$required_aes <- c("x", "y", "fun")

identical(GeomFunction$required_aes, GeomFunction2$required_aes)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In addition, because ggproto objects are environments, we can use `ls()` to see what they contain.

```r
ls(GeomFunction2)
#> [1] "required_aes" "super"
ls(GeomFunction)
#> [1] "draw_panel" "super"
ls(Geom)
#>  [1] "aesthetics"      "default_aes"     "draw_group"      "draw_key"       
#>  [5] "draw_layer"      "draw_panel"      "extra_params"    "handle_na"      
#>  [9] "non_missing_aes" "optional_aes"    "parameters"      "required_aes"   
#> [13] "setup_data"      "setup_params"    "use_defaults"
```

You can see that every layer in the hierarchy only contains the changes relative to the parent, and a mysterious `super` object, which is a function. When the `super` function is called, you can see that it retrieves the parent class.

```
class(GeomFunction2$super())
#> [1] "GeomFunction" "GeomPath"     "Geom"         "ggproto"      "gg"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The absence of a `super` object in `Geom` suggests that `Geom` is the root class.

The reason that the `ggproto` class exists is to allow extensions to reuse large chunks of code, without having to build them from scratch. In theory, ggproto is similar to R6 or reference class object-oriented programming, but I think R6/reference classes had some drawbacks that wouldn't allow cross-package inheritance of their classes.