# Animate Probability Density Function with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to replicate the [beta distribution animation of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#/media/File:PDF_of_the_Beta_distribution.gif) in R.

[image: beta distribution animation of Wikipedia]

Originally, I started with the following code

```
ggplot() +
  xlim(0, 1) +
  geom_function(fun = dbeta, args = list(shape1 = 5, shape2 = 5))
```

But I did not manage to use `gganimate` to animate the plot based on the shape parameters.

Therefore I tried a second approach where I first generate the data and then plot it using `geom_line()` (similar as in [this post](https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/r/creating-animations-ggplot2-plots/))

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

# get beta PDF for specific parameters ------------------------------------
calc_beta <- function(alpha, beta){
  X <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)
  PDF <- dbeta(X, shape = alpha, shape2 = beta)
  tibble(X, PDF)
}

# alpha and beta values ---------------------------------------------------
n <- 50
r <- exp(seq(log(0.1), log(5), length.out = n))
alpha <- c(rev(r), r, rep(5, 2*n), rev(r), r)
beta <- c(rep(5, 2*n), rev(r), r, rev(r), r)

# tibble with alpha, beta and PDF -----------------------------------------
dat <- tibble(alpha = alpha, beta = beta) %>% 
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(plotdata = map2(alpha, beta, calc_beta)) %>% 
  unnest(plotdata)

# plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
p <- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = PDF)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_time(time) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 4)) +
  annotate('text', x = 0.5, y = 4,
           label = 'alpha = {round(alpha[as.integer(frame_time)], 2)}
          beta = {round(beta[as.integer(frame_time)], 2)}') +
  labs(title = 'alpha = {round(alpha[as.integer(frame_time)], 2)}
          beta = {round(beta[as.integer(frame_time)], 2)}')
animate(p, nframes = 400, fps = 40)
```

[image]

Now I have 3 Qustions

1. Is there a way to use `gganimate` to animate the `args` of `geom_function` (first approach)?
2. Is there an easier solution then the second approach?
3. Why does the animate labeling not work within the `annotate()` function but only within the `labs()` function?

Comment: 1) I don't think so. To my knowledge gganimate animates aesthetics and not parameters. 2) your approach looks fairly straight forward to me. I don't think there will be a better option 3) annotate is a "fixed" layer and will not change with your animation (again, no aesthetics!). You could use geom_text instead, but you will need to create a data frame with one label for each state.

Comment: or you can use a stat where fun is an aesthetic... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636329/7941188